# Refactor stored procedure method in a separate class that accepts a varying number of parameters

Tags: c#

I am trying to refactor my stored procedure methods in a separate class. This is great because it reduces my methods (in the main class) to only a few lines of code. All connection strings and stored procedure (I call them templates) will be stored in a class called ConnClass. The problem I'm having is writing a method that accepts multiple parameters - but can only use one parameter if needed, or multiple if needed. Here is the method I'm using for one parameter:

```
public bool ExecuteProcedure1Paramater(string Proc, string AccountNumber)
{
    int j = 0;
    try
    {
        using (cmd = new SqlCommand(Proc, con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(sp.AccountNumberParam, AccountNumber);
            con.Open();
            j = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                sda.Fill(dt);
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log Exceptions
    }

    if (j > 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Here is the method in my main class that's opening the connection and passing the stored procedure names and parameter values, etc and filling a drop down list.

```
public void GetAccounts()
{
        //This procedure gets the parent account number along with other accounts associated with the parent account and places them in a DDL.
        //Arguments: Stored Procedure | Paramater
        ConnC.ExecuteProcedure1Paramater(sp.GetAccounts, txtAccountNumber.Value);
        cmbAccountNumbers.DataSource = ConnC.dt;
        cmbAccountNumbers.DataTextField = sp.MergedAccounts;
        cmbAccountNumbers.DataValueField = sp.MergedAccounts;
        cmbAccountNumbers.DataBind();
        cmbAccountNumbers.AppendDataBoundItems = false;
}
```

If I wanted to pass multiple parameters, I'd have to copy the code above (first example) and call it ExecuteProcedure2Paramater, ExecuteProcedure3Paramater, and so on - adding multiple parameters for each method. In my main class I would then choose whatever template was needed for that particular method (second code example). This seems like a lot of nonsense coding but I'll be using the same idea for all applications going forward. Is there a better suggestion and a better way for passing a varying number of parameters without having to create so many (templates)?

Comment: Sounds like you could benefit from an ORM. E.g. EntityFramework or Dapper or something.

Comment: Use a List<T> of sql param and have your caller that actually knows the names and values it wants to set pass them in.

Comment: That said, normally you'd want a lot more separation of concerns, and having one method per sproc would be expected to avoid breaking things, SOLID design etc.

Comment: I'm typing up a literal answer to how to do this, but it feels like malpractice. The short version is this: `public bool ExecuteProcedure1Paramater(string proc, Func<SqlParameter[]> getParameters)`. Your method takes as an argument a function that returns `SqlParameter[]`. Then it adds them to the `SqlCommand`: `cmd.Parameters.AddRange(getParameters());` The underlying problem is that your front-end code is tightly coupled to your SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

Create a structure to hold the variables and their properties of name and value such as

```
public class Variable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then make all calls such as:

```
public string CallSproc(string sprocName, params Variable[] variables)
{

...
    variables.ToList()
             .ForEach(param =>  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(param.Name, param.Value);
...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
public xxx yyyyy(string value1, string value2, string value3, string value4)
{
    SqlParameter[] sqlParameters = {
                new SqlParameter("@param1", value1),
                new SqlParameter("@param2", value2),
                new SqlParameter("@param3", value3),
                new SqlParameter("@param4", value4)
            };
    bool res = ExecuteProcedure("proc_1", sqlParameters);
    // ... do something
}
public bool ExecuteProcedure(string Proc, SqlParameter[] sqlParameters)
{
    int j = 0;
    try
    {
        using (cmd = new SqlCommand(Proc, con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            //here the params are added
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParameters);

            con.Open();
            j = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                sda.Fill(dt);
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log Exceptions
    }

    return j > 0;
}
```